# Post 'SELECT' Value To Next Page PHP

Tags: php, post

Here is the form code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID, NAME FROM b_sonet_group ORDER BY ID DESC");


echo "<form class='form-vertical login-form' action='step-2.php' method='POST'>";

echo "<h4 class='form-title'>Step One: Choose Your Project</h4><div class='control-group'><div class='controls'>";              

echo "<select>";
echo "<option value=''>Choose Your Project</option>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

  {
  echo "<option name='ID' value='" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['NAME'] . "</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";

  echo "</div></div>";

  echo "<div class='form-actions'><button type='submit' name='submit' class='btn green pull-right'>Proceed to Step Two <i class='m-icon-swapright m-icon-white'></i></button></div></form>";


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

What do I need to put on page 2 that retrieves the value ID from the form on the previous page and how do I print it so I can check it is the correct ID?

Simple I know but my brain has packed up and gone home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the name from option to your select. Then echo $_POST['id'];

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your `select` to

```
echo "<select name=\"project\">";
```

On your second page you can get the value with

```
echo $_POST['project'];
```

Comment: You should escape the " in your first example.

Comment: Ahhh.. Thought you had to put the name on the option value.  Works now! Doh! Thank you!